# Registration of different users in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have a site where each user can login and have his own control panel. The person who wants me to do it wants for each user to have separate part on site for registration. So, on my site I will have links "Register as a player" and "Register as a coach" because it is for a soccer club.

How should I handle passing of a parameter which determines user role? The problem is that I have four roles (SuperAdmin, Admin, Coach, Player) so that information is a little bit sensitive. I don't want that someone can set "userRole" to "Admin" and compromise the whole system.

```
create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "username"
    t.string   "userRole"
    t.boolean  "is_enabled"
    t.string   "firstName"
    t.string   "lastName"
    t.string   "password"
end
```

So, I am targeting to make something similar as those sites where they have regular users and part where people can register as an affiliate. Like "Become an affiliate" links on bottom of the site. So, people can register normally and can register as an affiliate.

What would be the smartest way to accomplish that? I need to determine somehow which user registers. I hope this is not to confusing.

Comment: how are you planning to set the user role?

Comment: That's my biggest concern. I can't do it so it would be visible as a parameter and I have those two ("Register as a player" and "Register as a coach") different parts of site where users can register. Maybe I should add some secret character somewhere and set it inside controller?

Comment: You can just have a user admin page to set the roles outside of registration, but that would involve manual setting up.

Comment: Ask your client how he wants to manage it.

Comment: @SherwynGoh - He wants to have "Register as a player" and "Register as a coach" links and when user registers he is registered as a coach or player, depending from which link he registered. He doesn't want to set roles by himself. He just wants to have power to enable/disable user. So, after each user registers, he will have new control panel, depending on who he is, coach or player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would personally create a separate table called `roles`, which will allow you to store as many different roles that you want:

```
#app/models/role.rb
Class Role < ActiveRecord::Base
   has_many :users
end

#app/models/user.rb
Class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :role

    before_create :set_role

    private
    def set_role
        role = self.role_id
        role = "0" unless defined?(role) # Default role
    end
end 

roles
id | name | created_at | updated_at

users
id | username | role_id | first_name | last_name | password | created_at | updated_at
```

This would allow you to set the "role" upon creating the user:

```
#app/controllers/users_controller.rb
def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    @user.save
    #see user model for before_create method
end
```

This would mean you can save custom roles if you want:

```
#app/views/users/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @user do |f| %>
   <%= f.hidden :role_id, "2" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: No problem - hope it helps! Might have to work on Strong Params to get it working 100%